# Inserting a PDF into jsPDF (dynamically fill in PDF Form)

Tags: javascript, pdf, jspdf, data-uri

You can create a PDF using jsPDF by inserting images and texts etc.. The thing is now I'm taking screenshots of the original PDF and converting them to Data URL to output a PDF form that has the text that the user supplies at coordinates on the page to fill in blank spaces on the PDF  `doc.text(20, 20, 'Info entered from HTML form .');`.

**The Problem:**

The images from the data URLs are blurry so the text doesn't look like the original PDF Form.

And users can't select the text.

---

I like the fact that you can position the users text on the PDF. but there is got to be a way to create this PDF so it's not so blurry. The only other option I could think of is copy the text and insert it line by line and position it properly.

Is there a way to use the whole original PDF in jsPDF and just position the text?

Do you have another method that you can share for filling in PDF forms dynamically?

I only know the language JS and I'm on windows.

Comment: Why don't you just insert the text that the user supplies into the PDF using jsPDF?

Comment: I don't understand your question. I do insert the text into the PDF the problem is having the original PDF there. How do Insert the original PDF so I can insert the text? The way I do it know is with images to make it look like the original. so they could print out the proper form with their answers. Do you understand?

Comment: All I know is that jsPDF allows you to output a PDF but you can't edit one that you have all ready.

Comment: Just ask for the bits you need from the user (in a web form, perhaps), then add these bits to the pdf when you create it.

Comment: Let me just say something. I didn't create the original PDFs. It is from an outside organization. so when you said "add these bits to the pdf when you create it"  I'm assuming you mean to when I create the whole thing. I'm trying not to type a 5 page form out and do all style adjustments with jsPDF. That's why I was wondering if there was a way to put in the text and boxes easily. and I thought there might be a way to do it by inserting the original pdf. this way users could select text.

Comment: If you don't want the text rasterised then you will need to either create the PDF yourself, or use a library that can manipulate PDFs for you. I know that https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/ can manipulate PDFs. I would suggest adding a small demo of the PDF and what it is you're trying to achieve.

Comment: So, what you want to do is server-side filling a form. For that, there are either products (such as FDFMerge by Appligent), or various libraries (iText, pdflib, and so on). The difference is the needed effort to integrate in your environment. From the description and the other comments, it looks as if you are trying to do something with a tool inappropriate for your task.